# PHP Array of items

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having multiple images (all which are clickable and have a value associated with each) on a page. Now I want to click any of the images (representing images) and that value is stored in array. So lets say I choose image of drink then meal then extras so everytime I choose one, it is updated in array as element. I am planning to do this in PHP so i was thinking something like PHP self submit? any illustrations are helpful...

Each time I add an item, I need a counter on the same page to increase/increment...

Thanks in advance and appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that only with PHP, as PHP is only executed before the page is shown.. You need to use Javascript and maybe AJAX to update your data on your back end.

Your best option is to add those highlighted items in Javascript and then send it via AJAX to your php handler.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use a very little bit of Javascript there, give the images an onclick-tag with an redirection or bind an event via jQuery. If you're experienced with jQuery use that otherwise use the onlick tag to append the id of your image.

example:

```
<img src="picture.png" onclick="window.location = 'index.php?meal=1';" />
```

You have to echo the id's in PHP of course.

Comment: That only goes to index.php passing meal = 1...

Comment: this is just an example how it should look in HTML, please read the sentence underneath. in your PHP you could make a for-loop echo'ing images with all paramaters you need.